# How to get the value of x:DataType directive specified on DataTemplate object in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

Unlike WPF, Xamarin Forms `DataTemplate` doesn't seem to have a built-in `DataType` property; instead, it's specified by the `x:DataType` directive in Xaml. Now, I'm trying to build a `DataTemplateSelector` that depends on the value in `DataType` property (`x:DataType` in Xamarin), but I got no luck getting its value. I've seen that a `DataTemplate` object in Xamarin has a constructor that takes a single type as an argument - I've even tried to use reflection to see if that type is saved in some private field; but, still no luck.

Any help to get back that value would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean this `Type` of `DataTemplate`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating#creating-a-datatemplate-with-a-type)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT No, I mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#using-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate) type of `DataTemplate`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#using-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate)

Comment: Okey , do you refer to its sample demo .(developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/DataBindingDemos) It also has this problem?You can expose some code.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes sir, so far, I couldn't find a way to get that value (value of `x:DataType`) back in code.

Comment: Unfortunately , this can not be getted.And when using `DataTemplateSelector` , you will know which `DateTemplate` be used.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector#creating-a-datatemplateselector